# MySQL AES_DECRYPT of mediumblob column with charset latin1

Tags: mysql

I have a database where there are 3 tables with 3 columns which are AES_ENCRYPTed.

One table has a column which is a VARCHAR(255) with charset latin1. It contains some text encrypted.
Applying the AES_DECRYPT with an UNHEX of the column value shows the output of the real value properly.

Another table has a column which is a mediumblob with charset utf8. It contains some large text encrypted.
Applying just the AES_DECRYPT and then casting it to char displays the original value properly too.

But the 3rd table has a column which is also a mediumblob but charset latin1. It contains a large JSON data stringified.

Now when I apply just the AES_DECRYPT('<column_name>', '') it outputs null. Applying unhex or casting the column to other types before the decryption did not do anything.

For the first 2 tables, just applying the AES_DECRYPT without the conversion also output something.
But the 3rd table does not output anything; just shows NULL.

Any idea what is happening here? It would be very helpful if someone with DB expertise can point me to the right direction why the output is NULL and what needs to be done in the query to get the real output.

EDIT:
The DB Columns are populated by a microservice which uses JAVA Hibernate ColumnTransformer for doing the write and read.
write = AES_ENCRYPT(, ), read = AES_DECRYPT(, )
The values posted via this is also returned properly in the GET response. But the same query does not output the 3rd column value and print NULL as described.

Answer (score 0):

With this structure :
[image]
And this command :

```
UPDATE encryption SET `encrypted` = AES_encrypt(CONVERT(`json` USING latin1), "key");
UPDATE encryption SET `decrypted` = AES_decrypt(encrypted, "key");
```

This works well for me.
However blobs doesn't any character sets...

Comment: Well, if I do it directly in MySQL it works. But another thing to add is that, the database column is populated via Java Hibernate ColumnTransformer. The same instruction is there. For write use AES_ENCRYPT, for read use AES_DECRYPT and it works properly in the POST request and also the API response sends the data back properly. But I dont understand why I can't get the same output for this specific column while doing the query manually.

Comment: NVM I found the issue. After making the last comment, I double checked the Java Code and that is where the culprit lied! Seems the encryption key was different (not intentionally!) for this specific column. Somehow it was missed. After using the wrong key, its giving the right value :,)

Thanks for you insights! And this discussion helped me got to the right track! I will just leave the question as is for future questioners to see this and if the same thing happens to them they will know what to check for and may be match this scenario!